# How to create png from unicode character?

Tags: image, unicode, fonts, character, file-conversion

I have been looking far and wide on the internet for images/vectors of unicode characters in any font, and have not found any. I need image files of unicode characters for the project I am working on, where I cannot just use text. Is there a way to "convert" unicode characters from a font into an image file? Or does anyone know where I can find this? Thank you.

Comment: On Windows, simply create an `HDC` canvas using `CreateCompatibleDC()`, then select the desired font into it using `CreateFont(Indirect)()` and `SelectObject()`, and then draw the desired characters as text on the `HDC` using `ExTextOutW()`, `DrawText(Ex)W()`, etc.  Then you can do whatever you want with the `HDC`, like draw it onscreen, save it to a `.bmp` file, etc.

Comment: Do you need a few specific characters? Or the ability to generate *any* unicode character as a graphic on-the-fly? If it is just a few, use @RemyLebeau suggestion or save as a PDF and convert that to an image, or display on a web page and capture an image to the clipboard, etc. If it is "any", why do you need images instead of a  regular font?

Comment: @manassehkatz I am creating a game that will use characters as assets, in other words, I need sprites of unicode characters, and will probably require a large amount of them. I am also unsure how to use RemyLebeau's code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76126154/imagemagick-annotate-with-unicode-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [BMFont Bitmap Font Generator](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) Supports Unicode, generates PNG images - looks like a perfect match.

Comment: Thank you so much sir :D