# Imagemagick annotate with Unicode characters

Tags: imagemagick, unicode-string

How can I draw Unicode characters in Imagemagick using -annotate ?

My spurce file is UTF-8

This is my code:

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q8\magick.exe" convert -size 800x200 xc:black -font Times -fill #808080 -gravity Center -pointsize 64 -annotate +0+0 "ABCDEF - Ê" text.png
```

What I get is this image
[image]

Comment: Create the text in UTF8 compatible text editor and save the file. Then put the file as @filename.txt (with the @prefix) into where you specify the text. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*):

```
print( 'ABCDEF - Ê'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp850'))
```

> ```
> ABCDEF - ├è
> ```

In terms of Windows command line: suppose that the following `76126154.bat` batch script contains the only command line `@echo ABCDEF - Ê` and is saved as `UTF-8` (**without** [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

Run the script using `UTF-8` as active console [Code Page](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html). Otherwise, you see mojibake as follows:

```
chcp
:: Active code page: 850

76126154.bat
:: ABCDEF - ├è

chcp 65001
:: Active code page: 65001

76126154.bat
:: ABCDEF - Ê
```